# How do I view the HTTP proxy 502 response body?

Tags: curl

I am trying to figure out why I am receiving `502 cannotconnect` from a HTTP proxy while using Curl.  The HTTP proxy immediately sends back 2548 bytes of a response body and I am hoping the response body has some clues.  I run Curl with `--verbose` but Curl does not output the response body from the HTTP proxy.  I tried capturing the output with `--output output.txt` but the output file is not created.

How do I view the HTTP proxy response body?

Here is my Curl command...

```
$ curl --verbose --proxy http://10.243.127.53:80/ https://myserver.com
* About to connect() to proxy 10.243.127.53 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.243.127.53...
* Connected to 10.243.127.53 (10.243.127.53) port 80 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to jira.oraclecorp.com:443
> CONNECT myserver.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: myserver.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 502 cannotconnect
< Content-Type: text/html
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Length: 2556
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
<
* Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT
* Connection #0 to host 10.243.127.53 left intact
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use Curl without `--proxy` and send the `CONNECT` request to the HTTP proxy.

Here is the Curl command.

```
$ curl --verbose -X "CONNECT myserver.com:443" -H "Host: myserver.com:443" http://10.243.127.53:80/
* About to connect() to 10.243.127.53 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.243.127.53...
* Connected to 10.243.127.53 (10.243.127.53) port 80 (#0)
> CONNECT myserver.com:443 / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Accept: */*
> Host: myserver.com:443
>
< HTTP/1.1 502 cannotconnect
< Content-Type: text/html
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Length: 2580
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
<
<html>
...
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 10.243.127.53 left intact
```